# Merge multiple PDFs and keep nested bookmarks

Tags: python, bookmarks, pypdf

I am trying to merge a few PDFs and keep the nested bookmarks all pdfs have a content parent in common when only one is needed, when i use the code below only the bookmarks of the last pdf in the folder are present in the merge, can anyone advise on what i need to change to have all the bookmarks preserved and a shared contents parent?
content
bookmark
bookmark
bookmark

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

os.chdir('filepath')
source_dir = 'filepath'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir('filepath') if isfile(join('filepath', f))]

for file in source_dir:
    fileReader = PdfFileReader(open(file,'rb'))
    outlines = fileReader.getOutlines()

merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False) 

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
        if item.endswith('pdf'):           
            merger.bookmarks = outlines
            merger.append(item)
            
merger.write('merged.pdf')
merger.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you run in your for loop:

`outlines = fileReader.getOutlines()`

you are overwriting the contents of `outlines` not appending to it. So it is not surprising you end up with only the last.

What is the type of `outlines`? Is it a list or similar? Consult the PyPDF2 documentation to find out, and work out how to build the appended outlines. Then adding the top level entries is your second task.

Comment: after considering your comment I found a way to append the outlines :) I am now faced with the issue that all bookmarks start on page 0 of the merged file but that's an issue for another day i think ... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

for anyone wondering this is the solution however all bookmarks from the merged pdfs start on page 1 (or 0 in code speak) anyone with a solution to this im all ears :)

```
record = []
for file in onlyfiles:
    fileReader = PdfFileReader(open(file,'rb'))
    outlines = fileReader.getOutlines()
    record.append(outlines)


merger = PdfFileMerger(strict=False) 

for item in os.listdir(source_dir):
    if item.endswith('pdf'):           
        merger.bookmarks=record
        merger.append(item)
        
merger.write('merged.pdf')
merger.close()
```